# Fill a data-attribute based on scroll position

Tags: jquery, css, custom-data-attribute

I am using progress circles which are using data attributes to determine how far the circle should be filled. The attribute is a number which I would like to change.

Now let's say the circle is at 50%. I want the circle to fill all the way up to 100% once the user hits a certain point at my page (let's say an ID). Can this be done by jQuery maybe?

Looking forward to your responses.

Thanks,
Jerry

```css
.progress-circle {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 15rem;
  margin: 4rem 2rem 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 15rem;
}
.progress-circle:before {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: attr(data-progress) '%';
  display: flex;
  font-size: 3rem;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1rem;
  right: 1rem;
  top: 1rem;
  bottom: 1rem;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease, -webkit-transform 0.2s ease;
}
.progress-circle:after {
  background-color: #0083ff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.progress-circle:hover:before,
.progress-circle:focus:before {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
          transform: scale(0.8);
}
/**
* $step is set to 5 by default, meaning you can only use percentage classes in increments of five (e.g. 25, 30, 45, 50, and so on). This helps to reduce the size of the final CSS file. If you need a number that doesn't end in 0 or 5, you can change the text percentage while rounding the class up/down to the nearest 5.
*/
.progress-circle[data-progress="0"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(90deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="1"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(93.6deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="2"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(97.2deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="3"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(100.8deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="4"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(104.4deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="5"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(108deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="6"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(111.6deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="7"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(115.2deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="8"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(118.8deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="9"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(122.4deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="10"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(126deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="11"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(129.6deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="12"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(133.2deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="13"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(136.8deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="14"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(140.4deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="15"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(144deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="16"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(147.6deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="17"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(151.2deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="18"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(154.8deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="19"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(158.4deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="20"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(162deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="21"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(165.60000000000002deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="22"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(169.2deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="23"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(172.8deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="24"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(176.4deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="25"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(180deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="26"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(183.60000000000002deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="27"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(187.2deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="28"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(190.8deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="29"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(194.4deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="30"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(198deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="31"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(201.60000000000002deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="32"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(205.2deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="33"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(208.8deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="34"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(212.4deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="35"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(216deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="36"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(219.6deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="37"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(223.20000000000002deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="38"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(226.8deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="39"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(230.4deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="40"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(234deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="41"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(237.6deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="42"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(241.20000000000002deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="43"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(244.8deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="44"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(248.4deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="45"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(252deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="46"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(255.6deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="47"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(259.20000000000005deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="48"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(262.8deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="49"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(266.4deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="50"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-90deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="51"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-86.4deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="52"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-82.8deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="53"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-79.2deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="54"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-75.6deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="55"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-72deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="56"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-68.4deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="57"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-64.8deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="58"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-61.2deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="59"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-57.6deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="60"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-54deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="61"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-50.4deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="62"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-46.8deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="63"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-43.199999999999996deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="64"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-39.6deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="65"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-36deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="66"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-32.4deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="67"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-28.799999999999997deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="68"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-25.200000000000003deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="69"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-21.599999999999994deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="70"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-18deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="71"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-14.399999999999991deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="72"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-10.799999999999997deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="73"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-7.200000000000003deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="74"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-3.599999999999994deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="75"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="76"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(3.600000000000009deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="77"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(7.200000000000003deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="78"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(10.799999999999997deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="79"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(14.400000000000006deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="80"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(18deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="81"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(21.60000000000001deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="82"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(25.200000000000003deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="83"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(28.799999999999997deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="84"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(32.400000000000006deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="85"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(36deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="86"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(39.599999999999994deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="87"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(43.20000000000002deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="88"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(46.80000000000001deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="89"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(50.400000000000006deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="90"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(54deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="91"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(57.599999999999994deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="92"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(61.20000000000002deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="93"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(64.80000000000001deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="94"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(68.4deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="95"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(72deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="96"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(75.6deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="97"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(79.20000000000002deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="98"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(82.80000000000001deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="99"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(86.4deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
.progress-circle[data-progress="100"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Pure CSS - Progress Circles  </h1>
    <p>This is a example of progress circles using only Stylus. </p>
  </div>
  <div class="progress-circle" data-progress="10"></div>
  <div class="progress-circle" data-progress="25"></div>
  <div class="progress-circle" data-progress="50"></div>
  <div class="progress-circle" data-progress="75"></div>
  <div class="progress-circle" data-progress="100"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/ - this might help you

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this? This will determine the `scroll position` / `height offset` within a `div` container (set to `overflow: scroll`) as you're scrolling, and then update the `data attribute` of `data-progress` with the determined percentage (rounded to a whole number). Once you reach the bottom of the scrollable `div`, it will be 100% on the progress circle. Depending on the amount of content in the scrollable `div`, you may need to adjust the `CSS` `height` size of the scrollable `div`, etc or alter the `JavaScript` for better handling of the percentage to ensure you don't end up with inconsistent results. This should be a good rough starting point for what you need.

```js
$('#content-scroll').scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  var contentHeight = $(this).height();
  var scrollHeight = $('#add-scroll-height').height();
  var scrollPercent = Math.round((scrollTop / (scrollHeight - contentHeight)) * 100);
  if (scrollPercent > 100) {
    scrollPercent = 100;
  }
  $('.progress-circle').attr('data-progress', scrollPercent);
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
}

.float {
  position: relative;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

#content-scroll {
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
  max-height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 200px;
}

#add-scroll-height {
  height: 1000px;
  padding: 3px;
}

.progress-circle {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 15rem;
  margin: 4rem 2rem 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 15rem;
}

.progress-circle:before {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: attr(data-progress) '%';
  display: flex;
  font-size: 3rem;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1rem;
  right: 1rem;
  top: 1rem;
  bottom: 1rem;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease, -webkit-transform 0.2s ease;
}

.progress-circle:after {
  background-color: #0083ff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.progress-circle:hover:before,
.progress-circle:focus:before {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
  transform: scale(0.8);
}


/**
* $step is set to 5 by default, meaning you can only use percentage classes in increments of five (e.g. 25, 30, 45, 50, and so on). This helps to reduce the size of the final CSS file. If you need a number that doesn't end in 0 or 5, you can change the text percentage while rounding the class up/down to the nearest 5.
*/

.progress-circle[data-progress="0"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(90deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="1"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(93.6deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="2"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(97.2deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="3"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(100.8deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="4"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(104.4deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="5"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(108deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="6"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(111.6deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="7"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(115.2deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="8"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(118.8deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="9"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(122.4deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="10"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(126deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="11"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(129.6deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="12"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(133.2deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="13"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(136.8deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="14"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(140.4deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="15"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(144deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="16"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(147.6deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="17"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(151.2deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="18"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(154.8deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="19"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(158.4deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="20"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(162deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="21"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(165.60000000000002deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="22"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(169.2deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="23"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(172.8deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="24"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(176.4deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="25"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(180deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="26"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(183.60000000000002deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="27"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(187.2deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="28"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(190.8deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="29"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(194.4deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="30"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(198deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="31"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(201.60000000000002deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="32"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(205.2deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="33"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(208.8deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="34"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(212.4deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="35"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(216deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="36"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(219.6deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="37"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(223.20000000000002deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="38"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(226.8deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="39"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(230.4deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="40"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(234deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="41"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(237.6deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="42"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(241.20000000000002deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="43"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(244.8deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="44"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(248.4deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="45"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(252deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="46"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(255.6deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="47"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(259.20000000000005deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="48"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(262.8deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="49"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(266.4deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="50"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-90deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="51"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-86.4deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="52"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-82.8deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="53"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-79.2deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="54"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-75.6deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="55"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-72deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="56"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-68.4deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="57"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-64.8deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="58"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-61.2deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="59"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-57.6deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="60"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-54deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="61"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-50.4deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="62"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-46.8deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="63"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-43.199999999999996deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="64"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-39.6deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="65"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-36deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="66"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-32.4deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="67"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-28.799999999999997deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="68"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-25.200000000000003deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="69"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-21.599999999999994deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="70"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-18deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="71"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-14.399999999999991deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="72"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-10.799999999999997deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="73"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-7.200000000000003deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="74"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-3.599999999999994deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="75"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="76"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(3.600000000000009deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="77"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(7.200000000000003deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="78"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(10.799999999999997deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="79"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(14.400000000000006deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="80"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(18deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="81"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(21.60000000000001deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="82"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(25.200000000000003deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="83"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(28.799999999999997deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="84"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(32.400000000000006deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="85"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(36deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="86"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(39.599999999999994deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="87"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(43.20000000000002deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="88"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(46.80000000000001deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="89"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(50.400000000000006deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="90"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(54deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="91"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(57.599999999999994deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="92"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(61.20000000000002deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="93"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(64.80000000000001deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="94"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(68.4deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="95"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(72deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="96"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(75.6deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="97"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(79.20000000000002deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="98"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(82.80000000000001deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="99"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(86.4deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}

.progress-circle[data-progress="100"]:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #0083ff 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, #0083ff 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="float left">
    <div class="progress-circle" data-progress="0"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="float left">
    <div id="content-scroll">
      <div id="add-scroll-height">
        Start scrolling this div....
        <br/><br/> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent id rutrum quam, ut lobortis neque. Integer fermentum ante vehicula diam fermentum vehicula a nec enim. Fusce efficitur ex ut lorem aliquet aliquam. Integer luctus, ex
        quis imperdiet aliquet, ipsum orci eleifend ex, non scelerisque nunc ligula eget nisi. Suspendisse congue eros elementum tortor volutpat rutrum in eu dui. Cras at iaculis leo. Cras accumsan sapien massa, quis fringilla sem egestas vitae. Sed nec
        feugiat velit. Suspendisse euismod fringilla interdum. Sed aliquet placerat ligula, ut gravida turpis ornare quis. Vivamus eget purus ultricies purus pulvinar sollicitudin quis et ipsum. Donec tincidunt odio posuere molestie laoreet. Nulla in
        justo eget lectus blandit tempus a vitae tortor. Donec id vulputate sem. Sed porta quam id metus sollicitudin, in volutpat arcu laoreet. Vivamus augue sem, semper id interdum congue, convallis ac leo. Sed varius sem ut ante malesuada, eu pulvinar
        lorem ullamcorper. Fusce vel augue nisl. In et est sem. Aliquam aliquet gravida nulla eget varius. Ut placerat sit amet nisl sit amet condimentum. Praesent quis egestas nulla. Donec in lacus id purus sodales condimentum eu vitae felis.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did this help? Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you for this.
It's sort of what I'm looking for. The thing is that the progress circle is inside the div that I want the scroll to be based on.